# Swift: print informative block description

Tags: swift, debugging, printing, block

While blocks are more comfortable to use rather than named functions, they significantly lack when debugging. I would be very happy if there is a way to get block context info, for example: location in code (file, line), captured variables, arguments etc...

P.S. Description in Xcode Variables panel displays block location, but 'Print description' command prints just `Fuction` in console

Answer (score 0):

Xcode's `Print Description` (which is equivalent to the lldb command line `po` command) is, in Swift, the way to access the "mirrors" in the Swift Runtime and Standard Library.  This is analogous to the ObjectiveC  `Print Description`/`po` which calls the `description` method on the object and prints the string returned thereby.  The Description is "the view the object wants to present of itself to the outside world", as opposed to the raw implementation level view.

Anyway, so if you want more information from `Print Description`, you should file a bug request with the Swift folks to enhance the mirror.

OTOH, the information you get in the Xcode Locals view is the lldb "data formatter" summary string for the function type.  See:

http://lldb.llvm.org/varformats.html

for more details.  You can override the data formatter for Function with one of your own to get more information.  That's true of any of the built-in formatters.  I haven't looked at how easy/hard it would be to dig up what you want.  But in any case, please file a bug with the swift-lldb bug reporter (or http://bugreporter.apple.com) to enhance the built-in data formatter with the information you need.